# While inserting my kernel module INSMOD exits with error "bad address", warns about "Kernel mismatch"

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, mismatch, insmod

I am developing this module for custom device that, in fact, a 4*8-bit i-o ports attached to ISA bus with addresses  0x0120 - 0x0123. This driver is based on "scull" by Alessandro Rubini and Jonathan Corbet. My OS is Ubuntu 10.04, kernel is 2.6.32-74 generic, I use built-in console-oriented compiler gcc.
While inserting compiled module using "insmod" I get an error "bad address" and module was not loaded. I've tried to debug it using "printk" and found out that my module successfully gets a range of i-o ports, major and minor numbers and then, when trying to do "Reset_Port" function it generates an error "bad address"  and exits.

Can anybody tell me, what am I doing wrong?

Here are __exit and __init functions of my module

```
void __exit ET3201_exit(void)
{
        int i;
        dev_t devno = MKDEV(ET3201_major, ET3201_minor);

        /* Get rid of our char dev entries */
        if (ET3201_devices) {
                for (i = 0; i < ET3201_nr_devs; i++) {
                        ET3201_trim(ET3201_devices + i);
                        cdev_del(&ET3201_devices[i].cdev);
                }
                kfree(ET3201_devices);
        }

#ifdef ET3201_DEBUG /* use proc only if debugging */
        ET3201_remove_proc();
#endif

        /* cleanup_module is never called if registering failed */
        unregister_chrdev_region(devno, ET3201_nr_devs);
    if ( ! port ) release_region(BaseIO, 8);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye, cruel world - ET3201 is unloaded\n");

        /* and call the cleanup functions for friend devices */
        /*ET3201_access_cleanup();*/
}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Set up the char_dev structure for this device. */
static void ET3201_setup_cdev(struct ET3201_dev *dev, int index)
{
        int err, devno = MKDEV(ET3201_major, ET3201_minor + index);

        cdev_init(&dev->cdev, &ET3201_fops);
        dev->cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
        dev->cdev.ops = &ET3201_fops;
    dev->CAMAC_Module_Number = CAMAC_Nmod;
    dev->CAMAC_Command_Adress = CAMAC_Adcom;
    dev->Driver_Number = ET3201_minor + index;
        err = cdev_add (&dev->cdev, devno, 1);
        /* Fail gracefully if need be */
        if (err)
                printk(KERN_NOTICE "Error %d adding ET3201%d", err, index);
}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int __init ET3201_init(void)
{
    int result = 0;
    int i;
    dev_t dev = 0;
    BaseIO = Base;  
    /* Get a range of minor numbers to work with, asking for a dynamic
    major unless directed otherwise at load time. */
    if (ET3201_major) {
           dev = MKDEV(ET3201_major, ET3201_minor);
       result = register_chrdev_region(dev, ET3201_nr_devs, "ET3201");
    } else {
           result = alloc_chrdev_region(&dev, ET3201_minor, ET3201_nr_devs, "ET3201");
       ET3201_major = MAJOR(dev);
    }
    if (result < 0) {
       printk(KERN_WARNING "ET3201: can't get major %d\n", ET3201_major);
       return result;
    }     
    port = request_region(BaseIO, 8, "ET3201");
    if ( port == NULL ) {
                        printk(KERN_WARNING "ET3201 cannot reserve i-o ports %lu \n", BaseIO);
                        return -ENODEV; 
            goto fail;
                }
         /*
         * allocate the devices -- we can't have them static, as the number
         * can be specified at load time
         */
        ET3201_devices = kmalloc(ET3201_nr_devs * sizeof(struct ET3201_dev), GFP_KERNEL);
        if (! ET3201_devices) {
                result = -ENOMEM;
        printk(KERN_ALERT "ET3201: can't get memory \n");
                goto fail; /* Fail gracefully if need be */
        }
        memset(ET3201_devices, 0, ET3201_nr_devs * sizeof(struct ET3201_dev));

        /* Initialize each device. */
        for (i = 0; i < ET3201_nr_devs; i++) {
                ET3201_devices[i].quantum = ET3201_quantum;
                ET3201_devices[i].qset = ET3201_qset;
                init_MUTEX(&ET3201_devices[i].sem);
                ET3201_setup_cdev(&ET3201_devices[i], i);
        }

        /* At this point call the init function for any friend device */
        dev = MKDEV(ET3201_major, ET3201_minor + ET3201_nr_devs);
        /*dev += ET3201_access_init(dev);*/

    printk(KERN_INFO "ET3201 is initialized with major %d\n", ET3201_major);
    if ( port != NULL ){
        printk(KERN_INFO "ET3201 is trying to reset %d devices\n", ET3201_nr_devs);
        result = Reset_Port();
    }
        if ( result != 0 ) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "ET3201: device cannot reset with result %d\n", result);
                result = -EFAULT;
                goto fail;  
        }
#ifdef ET3201_DEBUG /* only when debugging */
        ET3201_create_proc();
#endif

        return 0; /* succeed */

  fail:
        ET3201_exit();
    return result;
}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
module_init(ET3201_init);
module_exit(ET3201_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_ALIAS_MISCDEV(ET3201_minor);
```

and next will be Reset_Port()

```
static int Reset_Port(void)
{
int result = -EIO;
int count;
if (port == NULL) goto fail;
for ( count = 0; count < ET3201_nr_devs; count++ )
{
outb(0x00, ports[count]);
}
wmb();          /*write memory barrier*/
LastOp = E_Reset;
result = 0;     /* success  */
fail:   
return result;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(Reset_Port);
```

Now, after fixing 'int Reset_Port(void)' I've got another problem -
'WARNING: modpost: Found 1 section mismatch(es).'
After debugging I see that this is a result of calling 'ET3201_exit()'
from 'module_init()' - when I remarked this call, warning disappeared.
Surprising that exactly the same call was made in "scull" driver of respected authors - and it works. 
Question: What can lead to kernel mismatch in this code?

Comment: As for new problem, your `ET3201_exit` function is declared with `__exit` section attribute. This attribute means that section may be not created if module unloading feature is not enabled in the kernel. But you use this function in the `module_init`, which is used whenever module unloading support exists or not. That's why modpost reports about section mismatch: it is possible that `ET3201_exit` will be called when it is not exists.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thank you very much! I removed __exit attribute and section mismatch disappeared. __init and __exit attributes were not used in ''scull'' device driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! The bug is fixed - after declaring ' int Reset_Port(void) ' the module was inserted and removed successfully. I thought,(but it was wrong) that all functions that can be called from within ' module_init() ' must not be declared as static.

Comment: `module_init` **can use** static functions. But using `EXPORT_SYMBOL` for static function looks broken.

Comment: @Tsyvarev , thanks for useful comment! My 'module_init' use static function 'ET3201_remove_proc()' and it works well.